# WordPress delete link with redirect to home page

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I have the following link which allows an author to delete a post on my site but I need it to redirect to the home page afterwards because at the moment it tries to take the user to the post itself which of cause will throw a 404 as it no longer exists (not very user-friendly)

Here is the code: `<p id="delete"><a title="Delete your Favor?" href="<?php echo get_delete_post_link( $post->ID ); ?>">Delete your Favor?</a></p>`

How can I modify it to redirect to the homepage?

Answer (score 5):

According to the Wordpress 3.0.4 source code (wp-admin/post.php, line 223), going through that link calls the wp_trash_post function.

That function finishes by triggering a trashed_post action (wp-includes/post.php line 1838).

You can hook up your own handler to the trashed_post action (with [add_action](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action)) and do a wp_redirect.

Easiest way to do this: Your theme should have a functions.php file.

Add this to it:

```
add_action('trashed_post','my_trashed_post_handler',10,1);
function my_trashed_post_handler($post_id)
{
    wp_redirect( get_option('siteurl') );
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. Would you be able to provide some code? As I struggle with code with being able to see it. Thanks again.

Comment: @Cameron. Updated my answer. A quick note, i'm not entirely sure why you need to do that.. bit puzzled

Comment: Because the link is being used front-end and when clicked returns the user to the same page on postback which means 404 as it has just been deleted hence need to send the user to home page. BUT I only want the redirect to happen for the public one and NOT the delete link in the admin section!

Comment: Had written an update but didn't make sense. How do you authorise someone to delete a post? are they Authors, publishers, etc users?

Comment: 'trashed_post' of course! Unless you pass true to get_delete_post_link() as the 3rd parameter it is always going to be 'trashed_post'. I was looking at after_delete_post for ages. That hook only fires if you choose to force delete. +1'd your answer. Thanks